# create_Task(): The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, uwp

I have a UWP UI that calls native code that takes a while to execute.  Upon completion, the UI needs updating.  This is my code:

```
auto runOpti = create_task([this] { runOptimation(); });
runOpti.then([this]{postOptimation(); });
```

The postOptimation routine includes the line:

```
backwordCheckBox->IsChecked = params->backwards;
```

Executing this like gives the error in the title.

How do I get the postOptimation to run in the UI thread?

Thanks

Comment: This code apparently already runs on a task, so would not need create_task to create another one.  Pay attention to the stack trace in the debugger to see how it got there.  Do be careful with code like this, your user will quickly get bored watching grass grow, starts playing solitaire and your optimization won't finish.

Answer (score 2):

Good suggestion from Sornel!  Here's what worked:

Code inside postOptimation:

```
Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::High,
    ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([this]()
{

    backwordCheckBox->IsChecked = params->backwards;

}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the overload of `.then()` that takes a `task_continuation_context`, and set it to [`task_continuation_context::get_current_winrt_context()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt706512.aspx).

Using the `Dispatcher` (other answers) would work also, but this should compose better with PPL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Invoke method of the Dispatcher property: backwordCheckBox->Dispatcher->Invoke.

It's been quiet a while since I did anything with .net and I don't recall right off how to create an Action from a lambda, but that's how you'd do this.

Answer (score 0):

This code will ensure the operation gets executed on the UI thread that is associated with your 'backwordCheckBox' control:

```
backwordCheckBox->Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal,
    ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler ([this, params]
{
    backwordCheckBox->IsChecked = params->backwards;
}));
```